# Selecting one row from database then other rows for tabs active issue

Tags: php, html

I am setting a page that contains a tablist imported from database, the problem is that I want the 1st tab to be `class='active'` but when I add the class inside the while loop it take the class for all panels

Is there a way to select the 1st row only and give it the active class then select the other rows without it?

my code will describe it

```
  <?php
  $str_trans = "";
  $str_poem = "";

  $ebody_import_query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM ebody WHERE epoem_ie='$ie' ORDER BY rand()");
  if(mysqli_num_rows($ebody_import_query) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($ebody_import_query)) {
      $id = $row['id']; 
      $translator = $row['translator']; 
      $title = $row['title']; 
      $body = $row['body'];

  $str_trans .= "
  <li role='presentation'><a style='padding: 5px; font-size: 14px;' href='#$translator' aria-controls='$translator' role='tab' data-toggle='tab'>$translator</a></li>
  ";

  $str_poem .= "
  <div role='tabpanel' class='tab-pane' id='$translator'>
  <div>
   <u><b class='poemname'>$title</b></u>$body<br>
   <a style='margin-bottom: 10px;' href='translator.php?translator=$translator '><u><b>(جميع ترجمات  $translator_name)</b></u></a>
  <hr></div>
  </div>
  ";

  }
  }
  ?>

  <div class='status_post' >
  <div class='profile_main_column column ' style='margin-top: 10px; '>

  <ul class='nav nav-tabs' style='margin-bottom: 10px; ' role='tablist' id='profileTabs'>
  <?php echo $str_trans; ?>
  </ul>

  <div class='tab-content'>
  <?php echo $str_poem; ?>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a counter when you fetch the result of the query.

```
$counter = 0; 
if($counter === 0) 
  echo "<div class='active'></div>"
else 
  echo "<div></div>"
```

And at the end of your cicle you increment the `counter`, so that the `active class` is assigned only the first time.